# Что значат эти два утверждения про тип данных TEXT

Tags: mysql, текст, типы-данных

*Только начинаю изучение MySQL. На данный момент в книге идет введение, общий рассказ о том, что такое MySQL вообще. Поэтому никакого практического опыта у меня не имеется. Говорю на всякий случай, чтобы был понятен мой текущий уровень знаний в MySQL.*
 У меня в книге про тип TEXT написано следующее:
Символьные данные могут быть также сохранены в одном из наборов полей TEXT. Различия между этими полями и полями VARCHAR невелики.

- До выхода версии 5.0.3 MySQL удалял из полей VARCHAR все начальные и замыкающие пробелы
- В полях типа TEXT не может быть исходных значений
- В столбце TEXT MySQL индексирует только первые n символов (n задается при создании индекса).

Первый пункт мне понятен. Но непонятны 2 и 3.
**Вопросы:

1. О каких исходных значениях идет речь?

2. Что такое n мне ясно. Но я не понимаю о каком "индексировании только первых n символов" идет речь.**

Comment: а где именно пишут п.2? исходный текст бы глянуть. может там от контекста смысл зависит

Comment: @Lexx918 пункт 2 я написал: "в полях типа TEXT не может быть исходных значений". Никакого контекста нету

Comment: «О каких исходных значениях идет речь?» — о тех, которые прописываются в default в команде create table

Comment: @andreymal ааа.... Теперь ясно, спасибо)

Comment: @andreymal т.е. получается, что в Default и NULL не будет записано?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> я не понимаю о каком "индексировании только первых n символов" идет речь

Значения в текстовых полях зачастую имеют большую длину, например, ФИО заказчика, логин пользователя, название товара и т.п., и для поиска по этому полю нет смысла индексировать всю строку целиком. Если взять от каждой строки первые несколько символов, то скорее всего вы уже сможете сильно сократить область поиска. В этом случае и индекс можно строить только по этому числу символов.

Например, у вас онлайн магазин, в базе миллион единиц товара, все они имеют названия типа "Автомобиль" или "Стиральная машина". Если такие записи искать пользуясь только одной первой буквой (А и С в моём примере), то этого уже будет достаточно для сужения области поиска. Индексы по тексту и так занимают места больше чем сами данные. А таким образом можно сократить их размер не потеряв преимуществ.

Детали можно вычитать в документации:

[13.1.14 CREATE INDEX Syntax / Column Prefix Key Parts](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html#create-index-column-prefixes)